# Akka Scheduler, error with time unit

Tags: scala, akka

I am trying to send actor a postponed message. Thus I use the `Scheduler`, getting a code example from http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.0/scala/scheduler.html.

```
[error] /home/zeus/terra/src/main/scala/hw.scala:55: value milliseconds is not a member of Int
[error]         50 milliseconds,
[error]            ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed Aug 11, 2014 4:07:48 PM
```

Surprisingly, this error occured... Deleting the `milliseconds` from my code, another error appeared:

```
[error] /home/vador/death_star/src/main/scala/hw.scala:55: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Int(50)
[error]  required: scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration
[error]         50,
[error]         ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed Aug 11, 2014 4:12:32 PM
```

I do not see the point here.

Comment: Maybe mine is a dumb question but it's worth a try, have you `import scala.concurrent.duration._`?

Comment: Yes, in doing: `import scala.concurrent._`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Based on the comments, @Ende Neu was probably on the right track.

```
import scala.concurrent._
```

This does not give you the duration implicits. You need to also import those:

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
```

The actual implicits you want are on [`scala.concurrent.duration.DurationInt`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.duration.package$$DurationInt)

Comment: @Ende Neu Are there no shortcut like *.txt? Thank you both.

Comment: Nope, the underscore imports all the objects inside the concurrent package, but the conversions are inside the duration package, so you have to import that too.